# Monitor USB traffic

Tags: c#, c++, usb, monitor

I want to view all traffic going out the USB, with the potential to block data transactions to/from the USB based on content policy. How would this be done? Any way to achieve this in C#, or is it more of a C++ type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use things like [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx)() and [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx)() to handle this, but it's not going to be as easy as it sounds. Are you wanting to monitor all traffic from every possible device that could be plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this helps, but the #usblib project has been around for many years.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx